# Winforms ToolStrip.BackColor returns wrong color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, toolstrip

## The origin of my problem

I created a very simple dummy application in C# using winforms. It contains only a ToolStrip and a TrackBar inside that ToolStrip. The TrackBar should have the same BackColor as the ToolStrip, but it seems, that the property ToolStrip.BackColor does not return the actual background color.

```
public Form1()
{
    //// Here the ToolStrip is created.
    //// This code is generated by the designer.
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //// Here the the TrackBar is created.
    //// I think this is impossible to do via the Designer.
    this.CreateSpeedSlider();
}

private void CreateSpeedSlider()
{
    this.toolStrip.SuspendLayout();
    this.speedSlider = new TrackBar
    {
        TickStyle = TickStyle.None,
        AutoSize = false,
        Height = this.toolStrip.Height,
        Minimum = 0,
        Maximum = 10,
        BackColor = this.toolStrip.BackColor,
    };

    this.toolStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripControlHost(this.speedSlider));
    this.toolStrip.ResumeLayout();
}
```

The result is a white TrackBar on a light grey ToolStrip. So it seems that

```
this.toolStrip.BackColor
```

does not return the back color of the ToolStrip that is actually used to draw it.

## However...

If I change my function to

```
private void CreateSpeedSlider()
{
    this.toolStrip.BackColor = this.toolStrip.BackColor;
    ...
}
```

I get a white slider on a white ToolStrip. So ... assigning the value of the property to itself actually changes the color from light grey to white???

## So the question is...

Is there any good way to retrieve the correct background color of a ToolStrip without such 'hacks'?

And is this behaviour intentional or am I missing something?

Comment: The ToolStrip control inherits its BackColor property from the parent Form, but does not set it, unless you set it manually, keeping the default *neutral* Color (white-ish, should be `Color.FromArgb(248, 248, 248)`). So, when you add a TrackBar, it inherits the ToolStrip BackColor, equal to the Form's BackColor, but it instead sets it. So, if you want to host an *alien* semi-transparent control, set the BackColor of the TooStrip before hosting a control, or set the control's BackColor to the actual color of the ToolStrip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### BackColor is an ambient property

[`Control.BackColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor?view=netframework-4.8) is an ambient property:

> The BackColor property is an ambient property. An ambient property is a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control. For example, a Button will have the same BackColor as its parent Form by default. For more information about ambient properties, see the AmbientProperties class or the Control class overview.

It means that it is implemented like this ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs#L1135)):

```
public virtual Color BackColor
{
     get
     {
          Color c = RawBackColor; // inheritedProperties.BackColor
          if (!c.IsEmpty)
          {
               return c;
          }
          Control p = ParentInternal;
          if (p != null && p.CanAccessProperties)
          {
               c = p.BackColor;
               if (IsValidBackColor(c))
               {
                    return c;
               }
          }
          ...
```

There's an internal property `RawBackColor` which is the color explicitly set for this particular control. `BackColor` itself is calculated - if the color was not explicitly set for this control it will try to return the `BackColor` of its parent.

### ToolStrip is rendered differently.

To implement different styling for menus `ToolStrip` supports configurable [rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/toolstrip-technology-summary#rendering):

> ToolStrip classes implement a rendering scheme that is significantly different from other Windows Forms controls. With this scheme, you can easily apply styles and themes.

What it means, is that `ToolStrip` has a [`Renderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.renderer?view=netframework-4.8) and that renderer's initialization depends on system settings. So, in general there's no easy way to get the back color of a toolstrip.

Odds are good that by default [`ToolstripProfessionalRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer?view=netframework-4.8) is used. This type of renderer actually paints the background with a gradient. It has a [`ColorTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.colortable?view=netframework-4.8)  property which, in its turn, defines [`MenuStripGradientBegin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable.menustripgradientbegin?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ProfessionalColorTable_MenuStripGradientBegin) and [`MenuStripGradientEnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable.menustripgradientend?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ProfessionalColorTable_MenuStripGradientEnd).

So, in most (but not all) cases, you can determine the default back color for a toolstip this way:

```
var renderer = (ToolStripProfessionalRenderer)toolStrip.Renderer;
Console.WriteLine(renderer.ColorTable.MenuStripGradientBegin);
Console.WriteLine(renderer.ColorTable.MenuStripGradientEnd);
```

If you try to host a control with a uniformly-painted background, such as `TrackBar`, it will probably stick out in a gradient-filled toolstrip.

### ToolStripRenderer takes explictily set color into account

I couldn't find this behaviour documented anywhere, but according to [`ToolStripRenderer` source](http://internal%20bool%20ShouldPaintBackground(Control%20control)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(control.RawBackColor%20==%20Color.Empty%20&&%20control.BackgroundImage%20==%20null);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D), background is only painted (filled with gradient) if tool strip's `RawBackColor` is not set:

```
internal bool ShouldPaintBackground(Control control)
{
    return (control.RawBackColor == Color.Empty && control.BackgroundImage == null);
}
```

So, if you explicitly set `ToolStrip.BackColor` to any color, then the renderer will just use this color as a back color. This confusing behaviour explains why:

```
toolStrip.BackColor = toolStrip.BackColor;
```

has an actual effect.

### What to do now?

I can see multiple ways forward, none of them good:

1. Set the `BackColor` for both tool strip and track bar to some known color. This will kill the beautiful, beautiful gradient in toolstrip background. If you don't care much about gradient that's the easiest way to go.
2. Make the hosted control transparent, so the toolstrip's background shows through. This will not work for `TrackBar` as it doesn't support transparent background, for some reason. See this question, for possible options (I didn't try any of them): [Trackbar Background in a TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/652859).
3. Override track bar's `OnPaint` and fill it with a gradient, so that it blends in with a tool strip's background. This sounds problematic, but doable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's some crazy stuff going on in the framwork. I decided to write a custom paint method for the Trackbar to keep the gradient in the toolstrip and to paint the back of the Trackbar in the same gradient.